# youtube api upload file - Developer key required for this operation

Tags: java, youtube-api

I am trying to upload file to my youtube account but somehow I can't get it to work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public class YouTubeUploadService {
      String apiKey = "real-dev-api-key";
      String uName = "user_name";
      String uPassword= "user_password";
      public static void uploadVideo() throws Exception{

    YouTubeService service2 = new YouTubeService("olala", apiKey);

    try {
          service2.setUserCredentials("uName", "uPassword");
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
          System.out.println("Invalid login credentials.");
          System.exit(1);
        }

    System.out.println(service2.getVersion());
    UserProfileEntry userProfileEntry = service2.getEntry(new URL(profileUrl), UserProfileEntry.class);
    System.out.println(userProfileEntry.getAge());
    VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();

    YouTubeMediaGroup mg = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();
    mg.setTitle(new MediaTitle());
    mg.getTitle().setPlainTextContent("My Test Movie");
    mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.CATEGORY_SCHEME, "Autos"));
    mg.setKeywords(new MediaKeywords());
    mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("key word 1");
    mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("key word 2");
    mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
    mg.getDescription().setPlainTextContent("plain text");
    mg.setPrivate(false);
    mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.DEVELOPER_TAG_SCHEME, "tag scheme1 "));
    mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.DEVELOPER_TAG_SCHEME, "tag scheme 2"));
    newEntry.setGeoCoordinates(new GeoRssWhere(37.0,-122.0));
    newEntry.setLocation("Mountain View, CA");
    MediaFileSource ms = new MediaFileSource(new File("Wildlife.wmv"), "video/quicktime");
    newEntry.setMediaSource(ms);
    String uploadUrl = "https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

    System.out.println("Uploading");
    VideoEntry createdEntry = service2.insert(new URL(uploadUrl), newEntry);
    createdEntry.update();

    System.out.println("Done ---- Uploading");
}
}
```

when I run this code I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: Developer key required for this operation
```

GData`ServiceForbiddenException`Developer key required for this operation

```
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:605)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.insert(MediaService.java:400)
...
```

When I remove try{} catch block with code "service2.setUserCredentials("uName", "uPassword");" I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Unauthorized
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:608)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.insert(MediaService.java:400)...
```

What am I missing here? I got this code from google documentation.
Do I need to grant access to my account somewhere? If so please explain how, because I can not find it on google docs.

Comment: I fixed it. Problem was the way I was injecting the value of:
    
    String apiKey = "real-dev-api-key"; Ayway, this works now. So newer mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I was setting the value of propertie, String apiKey = "real-dev-api-key" in a wrong way. This is fixed and everything works now.